# test the convergency of $\arctan(k)$ series

Tags: convergence-divergence

Test the convergence of series

$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\arctan(3k)$

What i have done is

As we know that $$\arctan(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\arctan(3k)<\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

After that how do i find whether the series is convergentcor divergent

Help me please

Comment: Your inequality for the sum is incorrect since for negative terms, the inequality for the inverse tangent is reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\arctan(3k)$ to be convergent, first of all, we need to check if the general term of series tends to $0$ or not. In this case:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\arctan(3k)=\frac{\pi}{2}\ne0
$$
thus, the series **diverges.**

Comment: ndid not get anything from here please explain me

Comment: if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

Comment: But in above linit $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^{n-1}\cdot \arctan(3n)$=$\pm 1 \times \frac{\pi}{2}=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ is it right and can we say it is converge.

Comment: @jacky No, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\arctan(3k)\ne0$, therefore the first condition for a series to be convergent is not satisfied, therefore the series is **divergent**

Comment: Hint :$ \lim_{k} \arctan (3k) \not =0$. Hence?

Comment: @jacky Check the edit please.

Comment: Thanks so much Qurultay.